# De-Bug Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

**Question**

I am creating a rock paper scissors game. In terms of the functionality built so far it should:

1. Allow the player to select a choice
2. The computer then selects a random choice
3. The images representing the respective hands change
4. The winner is stated in text
5. The respective winner's score is updated.
6. 2. 3. all work perfectly.

But 4. and 5. I can not understand why they aren't working!

Please help me identify the issue :)

This is the code (I left out CSS because I don't think its important to the problem):

```js
if(document.readyState == 'loading'){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

let score = [0, 0];
let playerScore = score[0];
let computerScore = score[1];
const playerOptns = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
const computerOptns = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
let playerCurrentHand = [playerOptns[1]];
let computerCurrentHand = [computerOptns[0]];

function ready(){
    let choiceBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    for(let i = 0; i < choiceBtn.length; i++){
        let button = choiceBtn[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', changeHands)

    }
}

function changeHands(event){
    let buttonClicked = event.target;
    if(buttonClicked.classList.contains('rock')){
        changeToRock();
    } else if(buttonClicked.classList.contains('paper')){
        changeToPaper();
    } else if(buttonClicked.classList.contains('scissors')){
        changeToScissors();
    }
    computerRandom()
}

function changeToPaper(){
    document.getElementById('hand1').src="Assets/paper.png";
    playerCurrentHand = 'paper';
}

function changeToRock(){
    document.getElementById('hand1').src="Assets/rock.png";
    playerCurrentHand = 'rock';
}

function changeToScissors(){
    document.getElementById('hand1').src="Assets/scissors.png";
    playerCurrentHand = 'scissors';
}

function computerRandom(){
    let number = Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    if(number== 0){
        document.getElementById('hand2').src="Assets/paper.png";
        computerCurrentHand = 'paper';
    } else if(number==1){
        document.getElementById('hand2').src="Assets/rock.png";
        computerCurrentHand = 'rock';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hand2').src="Assets/scissors.png"
        computerCurrentHand= 'scissors';
    }
    compareWinner()
}

function compareWinner(){
    if(playerCurrentHand=='paper' && computerCurrentHand =='scissors'){
        computerWins();
       
    } else if(playerCurrentHand=='paper' && computerCurrentHand=='rock'){
        playerWins();
       
    } else if(playerCurrentHand=='scissors' && computerCurrentHand=='rock'){
        computerWins();
        
    } else if (playerCurrentHand=='scissors' && computerCurrentHand=='paper'){
        playerWins();
       
    } else if(playerCurrentHand=='rock' && computerCurrentHand=='scissors'){
        playerWins();
      
    } else if(playerCurrentHand=='rock' && computerCurrentHand=='paper'){
        computerWins();
      
    } else {
        tied()
    }
}

function computerWins(){
    computerScore++;
    score[0] = computerScore;
    let celebrationText = document.querySelector('.winner')[0];
    celebrationText.textContent = "Computer Wins";
    document.getElementByClassName('comp-score')[0].textContent = computerScore;
}

function playerWins() {
    playerScore++;
    score[0] = playerScore;
    let celebrationText = document.querySelector('.winner')[0];
    celebrationText.textContent = "Player Wins";
    document.getElementsByClassName('play-score')[0].textContent = playerScore;
}

function tied(){
    let celebrationText = document.querySelector('.winner')[0];
    celebrationText.textContent = "No Winner";
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
        <title>Rock paper scissors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="score-board">
            <div class="columned score-1">
                <div>
                    Player
                </div>
                
                <div class="play-score">
                    0
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="columned score-2">
                <div>
                    Computer
                </div>
                <div class="comp-score">
                    0
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="winner">
            Player Wins
        </div>
        
        <div class="hands">
            <div>
                <img id="hand1" src="Assets/paper.png">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img id="hand2" src="Assets/rock.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        
     <div class="buttons">
            
            <button class="btn rock">rock</button>
          
         
       
            <button class="btn paper">paper</button>
        
        
        
            <button class="btn scissors">scissors</button>
      
        
     </div>
       
            
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer**

There were two issues:

1. The query selector had an iteration count of [0]. This was because I changed it from getElementsByClassName() in an attempt to fix the problem.
2. At one point there was a getElementsByClassName() written as getElementByClassName()

Rookie errors, but glad its resolved. :)